# Why is there a difference between `0--3//2` and `--3//2`?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

I was figuring out how to do floor/ceiling operations without the `math` module. I solved this by using floor division `//`, and found out that the negative "gives the ceiling". So this works:

```py
>>> 3//2
1
>>> -3//2
-2
```

I would like the answer to be positive, so first I tried `--3//2`, but this gives 1. I inferred this is because Python evaluates `--` to `+`. So to solve this, I found out I could use `-(-3//2))`, problem solved.

But I came over another solution to this, namely (I included the previous example for comparison):

```py
>>> --3//2  # Does not give ceiling
1
>>> 0--3//2  # Does give ceiling
2
```

I am unable to explain why including the 0 helps. I have read the documentation on division, but I did not find any help there. I thought it might be because of the evaluation order:

If I use `--3//2` as an example, from the documentation I have that `Positive, negative, bitwise NOT` is strictest in this example, and I guess this evaluates `--` to `+`. Next comes `Multiplication, division, remainder`, so I guess this is `+3//2` which evaluates to `1`, and we are finished. I am unable to infer it from the documentation why including `0` should change the result.

References:

- *[6.7. Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)*
- *[6.14. Evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)*

Comment: -3//2 giving -2 *is* still giving you the floor; floor(x) is the largest integer lower than x, and -2 is the largest integer lower than -1.5.

Comment: @Hearth You are right, but the "spirit" of the question was seeking the ceiling of 1.5, not -1.5. But I understand that it is imprecise.

Comment: @KarlWilhelm Both the ceiling and floor of `-3//2` would be negative. The result for a positive number *will* be positive (neither function will "cross" zero). But you have a negative number; where were you planning on ignoring or dropping the negative sign?

Comment: @chepner I believe they mean they want to use this operation as a roundabout way of doing the ceiling for positive numbers. So they don't expect `-3//2` to be positive, they want to get the result consistently converted to positive in a way where they can use it effectively as `math.ceil(3/2)`.

Comment: @chepner The point of ``-3//2`` was just the first step for them to get the "ceil" of ``3/2``. The second step was converting it back to positive/absolute value, which triggered this question because it did not go quite as expected.

Comment: @chepner The comments by @Tyberius and @MisterMiyagi explain my thinking quite well. I am not planning on using this in a function either. It just started with a question on how to find the floor/ceiling without `math`, and then it evolved to a puzzle I could not explain.

Comment: "I guess this evaluates `--` to `+`" - that's not how operators work. The interpreter doesn't replace one operator with another. If given `--3`, it evaluates `3`, then it negates that when evaluating the right `-`, then it negates that again when evaluating the left `-` (but it just so happens that those last two steps cancel each other out here). If you try to apply the same process to `0--3`, it just doesn't work, because then you'd be left with a number next to a number (like `1 2`), which doesn't make sense. That's interpreted differently.

Comment: FWIW, I often use the `-(-a // b)` construction, but I usually comment it because it's not a common idiom. BTW, it's slightly more efficient than  `0 - -a // b`. And of course either version is more efficient than using the `math.ceil` function call. Also,  `math.ceil` isn't useful with very large integers.

Comment: Is that really more efficient than adding one to the floor, i.e. (a // b) + 1?  Are your math.ceil comments with respect to Python 2 or 3?  Apparently 2 returns a float (maybe this has something to do with you saying it isn't useful for large integers?) while 3 returns an int.  Genuinely curious as I don't do much Python.

Comment: @NotThatGuy You are certaintly correct, but that is beyond my knowledge when it comes to computer science. So the wording should be thought of the way I conceptualise it, and I think the answer is a lot more precise in their wording than me.

Comment: @ttbek: The advantage it has over adding one to the floor is that it gives the right answer! (For example, if a=4, b=2 then `(a // b) +1` gives 3 but ceil(4/2) is 2.

Comment: @psmears Ah, yes, in my haste I only considered cases where one would need to round in the first place.  The natural question is then, is it more efficient than adding one conditionally?  At this point I would guess that it probably is unless we have a faster test than are coming to mind at the moment (what jumps to mind is either mod or a second division, both of which are too expensive).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Python uses the symbol `-` as both a *unary* (`-x`) and a *binary* (`x-y`) operator. These have different [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

In specific, the ordering wrt `//` is:

- unary `-`
- binary `//`
- binary `-`

By introducing a `0` as `0--3//2`, the first `-` is a *binary* `-` and is applied last. Without a leading `0` as `--3//2`, both `-` are *unary* and applied together.

The corresponding evaluation/syntax tree is roughly like this, evaluating nodes at the bottom first to use them in the parent node:

```
 ---------------- ---------------- 
|     --3//2     |    0--3//2     |
|================|================|
|                |    -------     |
|                |   | 0 - z |    |
|                |    -----+-     |
|                |         |      |
|     --------   |     ----+---   |
|    | x // y |  |    | x // y |  |
|     -+----+-   |     -+----+-   |
|      |    |    |      |    |    |
|  ----+    +--  |   ---+    +--  |
| | --3 |  | 2 | |  | -3 |  | 2 | |
|  -----    ---  |   ----    ---  |
 ---------------- ----------------
```

Because the unary `-` are applied together, they cancel out. In contrast, the unary and binary `-` are applied *before* and *after* the division, respectively.

Comment: Ah, I am quite the novice, so it's the difference between `unary` and `binary` that got lost on me. After your answer I tried this: `0+--3//2 == 1`, so it makes sense that the first operator to the right of `0` is treated as a `binary` operator.

Comment: @KarlWilhelm This is where adding spaces and parentheses to your code will make it much more clear what's going on.  Unless you're writing for CodeGolf.SE, and trying to save bytes, it's better to more cleanly format stuff like this...

Comment: @KarlWilhelm A unary operation is a function that takes one argument.  A binary operation is a function that takes two.  I find it helpful to draw the parentheses when explaining what is happening.  `0--3//2` is `0 - (-3 // 2)`, while `--3//2` is `(--3) // 2`

Comment: Now I wonder whether in Python the “-“ in “-3” is the unary operator or part of an integer literal.

Comment: @CarstenS It's not part of the literal syntactically – the AST represents it basically as ``UnaryOp("-", 3)`` (just a lot less pretty). [An integer literal is just the absolute part](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals). However, it is evaluated when generating the bytecode and directly loaded as the value ``-3`` at runtime.

Comment: Nice unicode boxes. Do you use a tool to generate them, or is that just painstakingly elaborate handicraft?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You are correct, and I am normally very conscious on my code formatting. It might have helped me in this case, but my brain was in `puzzle` mode, so formatting was not really present. But now I have learnt a lot more, so maybe next time will go better.

Answer (score 30):

This is a simple matter of order of operations.

`--3//2` is the same as `(-(-3)) // 2`. Since there is nothing on the left-hand side, each `-` must be unary negation; and this has higher precedence than `//`; so `3` is negated twice (yielding 3) and then divided by 2.

`0--3//2` is the same as `0 - ((-3) // 2)`. Now that there is something on the left-hand side, the first `-` must be binary subtraction, which has *lower* precedence than `//`. The second `-` is still unary negation; `-3` is divided by `2` yielding `-2`, and then that value is subtracted from `0`.

Comment: Fixed the typo. A lot of small numbers in there after all.

Answer (score 18):

Another way to know how CPython actually calculates is to use the dis module to see what it actually does with its stack machine.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('0--3//2')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Whoops, constants are calculated during compilation, so use a name.

```
>>> t=3
>>> dis.dis('0--t//2')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (t)
              4 UNARY_NEGATIVE
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              8 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
             10 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```